# "foreach is not a member of object" when I'm trying to iterate over enumeration

Tags: scala

An example from a book:

```
object Breed extends Enumeration {
  val doberman = Value("Doberman Pinscher")
  val yorkie = Value("Yorkshire Terrier")
  val dane = Value("Great Dane")
  val portie = Value("Portuguese Water Dog")
}
// print a list of breeds and their IDs
println("ID\tBreed")
for (breed <- Breed) println(breed.id + "\t" + breed)
```

It says that foreach is not a member of object Breed.